# How to prove two closed intervals are equinumerous?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $[0,1] \approx [-\pi,e^2]$

(The notation $\approx$ is used to denote equinumerous)

I know to prove two closed intervals are equinumerous I need to show a bijective function that will map from one interval to the other but I cannot seem to find the correct mapping.

Comment: Can you find a linear function that maps $0$ to $-\pi$ and $1$ to $e^2$?

Comment: $f(x)=x(e^2+\pi )-\pi$ I have come up with this @EthanBolker

Comment: Hint: Think of the line joining $(0,-\pi)$ and $(1,e^2)$. Write the equation of this line in the form $y=mx+c$

Comment: @ECollins I guess you can answer your own question now ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $[-\pi, e^2] \cong [0, e^2 + \pi]$

Edit: I don't understand why I received a downvote so here's the full solution: The linear function from $[0,1] \to [0, e^2 + \pi]$ is just multiplication by $e^2 + \pi$ and is clearly a bijection. We then compose this with the map which subtracts $\pi$. This composition is a composition of bijections and is therefore a bijection.

Comment: I think your hint is to a more sophisticated/complex solution (which you only provided just now) than to the more straightforward "find a linear function". And that simpler solution was already hinted at. (Not my downvote).